# Telethon: check if message has replies?

Tags: python, telethon, telegram-api

Let's assume we have replies with this structure:

1─┐        (How are you today?)
     2─┐   (I'm fine, thanks. And you?)
          3   (I'm all right.)

And I somehow got second message. I know that I can `get_reply_message` - this way I will get message `1` (current message replied to).

But how can I get message `3` (a message replied to a current message)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `id` of the last reply to your `1` message with (change `GROUP` and `MESSAGE_ID`):

```
message = await client.get_messages(GROUP, ids=MESSAGE_ID)
last_reply_msg_id = message.replies.max_id
```

You will have the id of the message `3` in `last_reply_msg_id`, then just use `client.get_messages` once again to get the full message object

Comment: I will check the solution and then react. Thanks!